# Why does Pandas Series.subtract method perform differently from subtract operator

Tags: python, pandas

This is no doubt an edge case, it appears that the subtract method and operator behave in the same for `dtype float`, but not for `dtype datetime64[ns]` (see below).  Is that a bug or intentional behavior?

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series(dtype='datetime64[ns]')
s2 = pd.Series(dtype='datetime64[ns]')

s3 = pd.Series(dtype='float')
s4 = pd.Series(dtype='float')
```

The subtract operator yields:

```
s1 - s2
TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')

s3 - s4
Series([], dtype: float64)
```

Whereas the subtract method yields:

```
s1.subtract(s2)
Series([], dtype: timedelta64[ns])

s3.subtract(s4)
Series([], dtype: float64)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. But you can do `pd.to_timedelta(s1) - pd.to_timedelta(s2)` for now.